# Memory leaks in C# while using C++/CLI defined class with finalizer

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, c++-cli, finalizer

When I implement a class in C++/CLI DLL:

```
public ref class DummyClass
{
protected:
    !DummyClass() 
    {
        // some dummy code:
        std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

and when I load that DLL to C# project and use the class just by repeatedly creating an object:

```
static void Main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        var obj = new DummyClass();
    }
}
```

then, while running the program, memory is slowly digested to OutOfMemoryException.

It seems, that this memory leak (or bad work of garbage collection) happens everytime I implement finalizer in C++/CLI.

**Why happens this memory leak? How could I avoid it and be still able to use finalizer for some other (more complicated) use?**

---

**UPDATE:** The cause surely is not in writing to Console / stdout or other non-standard code in finalizer, the following class has the same memory leaking behaviour:

```
public ref class DummyClass
{
private:
    double * ptr;
public:
    DummyClass()
    {
         ptr = new double[5];
    }
protected:
    !DummyClass() 
    {
         delete [] ptr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Writing to the `Console`/`stdout` will cause it. See http://xacc.wordpress.com/2011/02/22/gc-suppressfinalize/ for my observations and some comments. The general rule in .NET classes, do not do anything in the finalizer (except for implementing `IDisposable` correctly).

Comment: I updated the question, so you can see, that even when you do what you should do in the finalizer (e.g. deleting unmanaged resources), you still get the same memory leaking results.

Comment: Not sure about that, but I think I recall C++/CLI has both a finalizer and a destructor (indeed so `~DummyClass` for destructor). Try that instead.

Comment: Here is relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15339608/c-cli-best-practice-for-free-gchandle-in-the-finalizer?rq=1

Comment: Some more info from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177197(v=vs.100).aspx (All too confusing for me ;p)

Comment: @leppie: I tried lots of combinations with destructor `~DummyClass` and combinations of destructor and finalizer, but anytime I use also finalizer `!DummyClass`, then I get to this problem.

Comment: I guess you need to use the `IDisposable` pattern then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you allocate faster than you can garbage collect you will run into OOM. If you do heavy allocations the CLR will insert a Sleep(xx) to throttle allocation but this is not enough in your extreme case.

When you implement a finalizer your object is added to the finalization queue and when it was finalized it is removed from the queue. This does impose additional overhead and you will make your object life longer than necessary. Even if your object could be freed during a cheap Gen 0 GC it is still referenced by the finalization queue. When a full GC is happening the CLR does trigger the finalizaion thread to start cleaning up. This does not help since you do allocate faster than you can finalize (writing to stdout is very slow) and your finalization queue will become bigger and bigger leading to slower and slower finalization times.

I have not measured it but I think even an empty finalizer will cause this issue since the increased object lifetime and two finalization queue handling (finalizer queue and f-reachable queue) do impose enough overhead to make finalization slower than allocation.

You need to remember that finalization is an inherent asynchronous operation with no execution guarantees at a specific point of time. The CLR will never wait to clean all pending finalizers before allowing additional allocations. If you allocate on 10 threads there will still be one finalizer thread cleaning up after you. If you want to rely on deterministic finalization you will need to wait by calling GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
but this will bring your performance to a grinding halt.

Your OOM is therefore expected.

Comment: THANK YOU! When I inserted `Thread.Sleep(1000);` after each 1000000th DummyObject creation (so GC has its time), memory stopped leaking!

Comment: Suggested `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()` once per Xth iteration solves the problem too. Thanks.

Comment: It is not the GC taking its time it is the exeuction time of the finalizer thread that is the limiting you. If you can make the finalizer run faster you do need less frequently to stop.

Comment: FYI: when GC tries to collect an object with finalizer, it not only puts it into finalization queue, but also that object gets promoted to a generation+1 - because its 'ghost' survived a sweep. I've read about that no longer than year ago in some article at either the MSDN or RedGate's white papers. Sorry, but I don't have a link right now:/

Comment: @AloisKraus Why do you believe that the CLR adds a sleep statement to throttle allocations? Can you site an on-line reference. I have searched for days and can't find anything. See comment in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68960474/643828) by Konrad Kokosa.

Comment: @BobBryan: See CoreClr: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/runtime/main/src/coreclr/gc/gc.cpp in method gc_heap::allocate_soh. If 140 allocations on SOH (Small Object Heap) did happen and  a Background GC is running a 2ms sleep is added. This effectively throttles your allocation rate.

Comment: @AloisKraus Thank you for the code link. While it does sleep under these conditions, it looks to me that the rationale for this is only to support the background GC. Would you disagree too much with this? It sort of makes sense that allocations might interfere with a background GC.

Comment: @BobBryan: You can try it out. Allocate in a loop and look with a profiler in your allocation method. Then you will find that you are blocked by thread sleeps.  At some point GC is running. If you are allocating like crazy then a background GC will always be active. This boils then down to throttling the allocator. Yes it supports GC. What would happen if you can produce faster garbage than the GC is able to clean up? By default background GC is active. There are many other Thread Sleeps in that class. You can turn off background GC and look with a profiler where throttling then happens.

Comment: @BobBryan: Count != Time. If you allocate 140 times within 1us and then sleep for 2ms you are slowing down allocations by 3 orders of magnitude. Also if you are at a server where the timer tick granularity is 15ms by default you are always sleeping 15ms.

Comment: @AloisKraus I think my initial idea about how much of an impact sleeping for 2 ms after every 140 times through the loop was not quite correct. A little math can be shown to validate this. Assume that a thread can execute 200 million high level instructions per second. Also, assume that it takes 200 instructions to allocate an average object on the heap. 200 million / 200 = 1 million allocations per second. 1 million allocations / 140 = 7,143 threads that will be sleeping 2 ms after 1 second. So, the call to Sleep here does have a significant impact.

Comment: @AloisKraus bgc_alloc_spin_count is getting set by GetBGCSpinCount. However, I can't find the definition of GetBGCSpinCount anywhere - any ideas? Is gc.cpp out of date?

Comment: @BobBryan: See https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/runtime/main/src/coreclr/gc/gcconfig.h and https://github.com/kosmos-zhang/dotnet.coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/clr-configuration-knobs.md.  I would expect if you ask such advanced questions that you know how to read and locate code. That is not hard to find.

Comment: @AloisKraus Actually, I did find gcconfig.h and gcconfig.cpp a couple of days ago. But, I did not find a specific definition for GetBGCSpin or GetBGSpinCount. After looking at the code again, it looks like it is using a macro that is used to generate these method names. Sorry, my C++ is a little rusty. I think I get it now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the AddMemoryPressure function, otherwise the garbage collector underestimates the need for cleaning up these objects in a timely manner.