# When allocating with the new keyword, does the CLR ever throttle via a Sleep statement when memory is low?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, new-operator, throttling, low-memory

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15522966/643828) here on Stack Overflow:

*When you allocate faster than you can garbage collect you will run into OOM. If you do heavy allocations the CLR will insert a Sleep(xx) to throttle allocation but this is not enough in your extreme case.*

So, I have not read anything about the CLR throttling allocations by inserting a Sleep statement to slow down allocations when memory is low. Can anyone confirm if this is true or not? If it is true, then is there any documentation that talks about the details? I have tried doing Google searches, but could not find anything to support this claim.

Comment: I don't think there's a requirement in the CLR spec that says this *has* to happen, but it sounds like an implementation may *choose* to throttle a thread. (Whether it does this by actually doing a Sleep operation or if there's some other mechanism, I don't know.) .NET is not specifically designed for realtime applications, so the spec makes few concrete timing guarantees.

Comment: Be carful of what you read and believe

Comment: @mjwills I'm asking the question because I'm thinking about writing a custom class similar to the ArrayPool class that provides the option to throttle new allocations when memory is low. If the CLR is already doing that, then this would not be appropriate for a custom class to duplicate - right? So, are you saying that I can't ask a question for the sake of knowing how something works, and that I have to have a good underlying reason for asking the question? It almost sounds like you are implying that such questions are only asked by developers who don't quite understand what they are doing.

Comment: I am not saying that at all. It felt like a XY Problem, and I wanted to help you solve your real underlying problem. Now we know more about what your real underlying problem is. Perhaps consider mentioning that context in the question itself to help us better assist you? More context is helpful, since it gives us more information to help us help you - for example, we may have other ideas that may be of assistance.

Comment: For the specific type you are planning to pool - is it likely to live inside the LOH? Can you talk us through why you think pooling may be of benefit?

Comment: @mjwills I am planning on writing a blog article about some of the pitfalls of ArrayPool and how it can be better designed.. I will post a link back here when it is ready. It will probably be a while because I'm still writing tests for it. In answer to your LOH question, one of the problems with ArrayPool is that it does not pool arrays with a length > 2 ^ 20 (1,048,576). So, yes the class I want to write will support pooling larger array lengths.

Comment: The General - I was skeptical of the claim, which is why I posted the question. I am hoping that someone like @EricLippert would share his vast knowledge of the CLR and be able to definitively tell us if this is the case or not.

Comment: @Bob the *default* array-pool has those chosen limits; can you not just... use a non-default pool with different limits? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraypool-1.create?view=net-5.0#System_Buffers_ArrayPool_1_Create_System_Int32_System_Int32_

Comment: I don't really know why @Alois Kraus has claimed this "Sleep" thing, but i am completly not aware of anything like that in the CLR...

Comment: @MarcGravell No, not really. I am looking to move away from both maximum array length and buckets in general. I think the current scheme of using power of 2s to determine the bucket index is a little wasteful (i.e. requesting a buffer length of 524,289 and then receiving an actual length of 1,048,576). The class user should have more control over how this works, including the capability to specify an exact match for special cases.

Comment: Slowing down an allocating thread would only make sense if a concurrent garbage collector is active (don’t know whether C# had one back in 2013). As otherwise, the  allocating thread will either, being stopped during GC or performing the GC itself, so there’s no possibility for the GC not to catch up. But even for a concurrent garbage collection, there’s no sense to use *Sleep(xx)*, when the runtime has everything it needs to insert a wait for the completion of the GC exactly (that’s how it works in Java when memory is exhausted; don’t see a reason for C# to do it differently).

Comment: @Holger I had started to think along these lines about a few hours ago when I read about the [2019 article](https://www.ageofascent.com/2019/02/04/asp-net-core-saturating-10gbe-at-7-million-requests-per-second/) showing that ASP.NET Core (2.2) processing just over 7 million requests per second. I don't see how these numbers could be obtained if a thread is sleeping for even 1 ms. Your point about the GC stopping all managed threads to catch up is well taken. This suggests that a custom Array Pool class should not throttle allocations by sleeping.

Comment: I think, that’s the right conclusion, just let the runtime do its job. Mind that in one point, the linked answer is right. When you’re using finalizers and allocate objects with finalizers at a high rate, the finalization may indeed fail to catch up (and the runtime doesn’t even try to fix that issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to @AloisKraus for his [research, patience, and links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15522966/643828) to the code in [GC.cpp](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/coreclr/master/src/gc/gc.cpp) that shows the following code in the method gc_heap::allocate_small:

```
#if defined (BACKGROUND_GC) && !defined (MULTIPLE_HEAPS)
    if (recursive_gc_sync::background_running_p())
    {
        background_soh_alloc_count++;
        if ((background_soh_alloc_count % bgc_alloc_spin_count) == 0)
        {
            add_saved_spinlock_info (false, me_release, mt_alloc_small);
            leave_spin_lock (&more_space_lock_soh);
            bool cooperative_mode = enable_preemptive();
            GCToOSInterface::Sleep (bgc_alloc_spin);
            disable_preemptive (cooperative_mode);
            enter_spin_lock (&more_space_lock_soh);
            add_saved_spinlock_info (false, me_acquire, mt_alloc_small);
        }
        else
        {
            //GCToOSInterface::YieldThread (0);
        }
    }
#endif //BACKGROUND_GC && !MULTIPLE_HEAPS
```

The key line is:

```
GCToOSInterface::Sleep (bgc_alloc_spin);
```

bgc_alloc_spin is initialized to 2, so this causes the thread to sleep for 2 milliseconds (ms). The code is only executed once every 140 times it is called, and only when there is a background GC taking place. But, this is still enough to cause 14,000+ threads to sleep for 2 ms over the course of 1 second, which will have a significant impact on performance (see the Alois Kraus discussion for the simple math).

**Edit 1**

In answer to @Enigmativity, the GCToOSInterfaceSleep method is defined as:

```
void GCToOSInterface::Sleep(uint32_t sleepMSec)
{
    ::Sleep(sleepMSec);
}
```

This is located in [gcenv.windows.cpp](https://github.com/mattwarren/GCSample/blob/master/sample/gcenv.windows.cpp).

In conclusion, the answer to the question I posed is yes, the CLR does throttle allocations when a background GC is running. The rationale to throttling allocations appears to be to allow the background GC to complete its job more quickly and efficiently.

Comment: What's weird here it that Windows has a min sleep of about 16ms. There's no point sleeping for 2ms as it will always be 16ms or more. Can you also post the code that actually performs the sleep?

Comment: I don't want to go back-and-forth on this. Can you please show where that implementation leads? The call `::Sleep(sleepMSec);` doesn't explain anything. Please help go down the rabbit hole all of the way.

Comment: The whole discussion can be out-of-date, as `dotnet/coreclr` was too old (more than 1.5 years). You cannot see that piece of code `allocate_small` any more in latest `dotnet/runtime` repo's [gcc.cpp](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/runtime/main/src/coreclr/gc/gc.cpp). Anyway now you know how to dig the source code and help yourself out.

Comment: @LexLi It looks like the code that was in allocate_small has been renamed to gc_heap::allocate_soh. It still sleeps and the logic is just like the old code - right? I do appreciate your efforts to make available the latest version of gc.cpp. By the way, do you know where the implementation of ::Sleep is defined? I found the function definition in synchapi.h, but could not find the implementation, since there does not appear to be a synchapi.cpp.

Comment: @Enigmativity I'm afraid I could not find the implementation for Sleep. I did find a link to [this blog](https://shauncassells.wordpress.com/2020/01/03/bug-win32-sleep-api-is-not-always-accurate-below-100ms/), which suggests that anyone can set the min sleep time. I really don't think that Microsoft would allow users to impact GC operations, so I think the GC uses a different version of Sleep, which is probably set to a min of 1 ms. Try posing this as an SO question, and you will probably get much better answers.

Comment: @BobBryan - The windows clock can't go below 16ms, so I don't think it's a normal timer.